# native javascript equivalent to jquery.append when iframes are present

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use native javascript to append a string of html to a target div.  This works fine using:

```
var selector = document.getElementById('divid');
var str = '<div><h1>string of html content</h1></div>';
selector.innterHTML += str;
```

Except whenever the document contains an iframe it seems to hide the frame when appending the innerhtml.  I tried a work around as follows:

```
var selector = document.getElementById('divid');
var str = '<div><h1>string of html content</h1></div>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
selector.appendChild(div);
```

This works but now I am creating an unnecessary div container, is there a way to do this without creating a new element that won't erase the iframe?

Comment: I showed you my d, its str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Except whenever the document contains an iframe it seems to hide the frame when appending the innerhtml

See ["innerHTML += ..." vs "appendChild(txtNode)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2305654/1048572) for the reason - modifying `innerHTML` creates a new iframe that reloads. Also have a look at [What is better, appending new elements via DOM functions, or appending strings with HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8461851/1048572)

> This works but now I am creating an unnecessary div container

Just don't create an extra `div`, you have one in your HTML anyway:

```
var selector = document.getElementById('divid');
var div = selector.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.innerHTML = '<h1>string of html content</h1>';
```

> is there a way to do this without creating a new element that won't erase the iframe?

You can also use the [native `insertAdjacentHTML` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) which is the equivalent to jQuery's `append` with a HTML string:

```
var selector = document.getElementById('divid');
selector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div><h1>string of html content</h1></div>');
```

Comment: seems to work, never used insertAdjacentHTML before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var el = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
selector.appendChild(el.childNodes[0]);
```